# Are there any numeric suffixes for specifying a double?

Tags: c++

```
void Foo(float  a){}  //1
void Foo(double a){}  //2 overloaded


Foo(1.0f);                           //calls function 1
Foo(1.0 /*double numeric suffix?*/); //calls function 2
```

If not, is a cast the only way this can be achieved?  I am mainly interested in
ensuring double precision math during certain operations, etc:

```
ulong j;
double v;

j = /*some value*/;
if(j>0UL)
  v = 1.0 / j;  //if 1.0 is set as a float by the compiler then
                //could it be likely we lose some precision here 
                //if a double would allow for more precision?  Is
                //a cast the only means of ensuring double precision?
```

Other tips on allowing the compiler to auto-determine the types during an operation would be helpful.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A suffix is unnecessary in C++.  Any floating point value which lacks the 'f' suffix will be typed to the compiler type double by default.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_0x

Comment: Disagree with that. Consider 2 functions overloaded, void foo(int); void foo(double);
If you want to call the 2nd with double value 5, you must explicitly write foo(5.0) which can be cumbersome in some situation where the 5.0 value is not hardcoded but come from some computation or parsing.