# Why does this float have 2 different values?

Tags: c, floating-point, int

When I do this:

```
float add=0;

int count[] = {3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}
for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
    add += 1 / ((float)count+1);
```

The output is:

```
4.00000000000000000000
```

But when I do this:

```
float add=0;

int count[] = {3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}
for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
    add += 1.0 / ((float)count+1);
```

The output is:

```
3.99999976158142089844
```

When I need to turn an int into a float, I either add `(float)` in front or let it do arithmetic with a decimal such as `a / 1.0`. Is there any difference?

Edit:
Adding the desired behaviour.

The reason is that afterwards, I need a result that adds `add` to another int variable for an int output. However, when I do it the second way, the int uses 3 instead of 4 so I would like to know what is the difference between the first and second code.

Comment: Before posting any question please make sure that your code is error free.

Comment: 1) you can't declare `int count=[3 2 1 3 1 2 3 3 1 2 1]` in C 2) float arithmetic is not what you think it is

Comment: This doesn't look like C to me.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: even if you make it valid C, the big difference is that [`1.0 ` is a double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1534600/995714), hence the whole expression will be done in double precision, whereas `1 / ((float)count+1)` is done in float precision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't C, but this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
        float add = 0;
        int count[] = { 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                add += 1 / ((float) count[i] + 1);
        }
        printf("%f\n", add);
        return 0;
}
```

I've executed this code with `add += 1 / ((float) count[i] + 1);` and `add += 1.0 / ((float) count[i] + 1);`.

In both cases, `printf("%f\n", add);` prints `4.000000`.

However, when I print each bit of the variable `add`, it gives me `01000000011111111111111111111111` (3.9999998) and `01000000100000000000000000000000` (4)

As pointed by phuclv, this is because `1.0` is a `double`, hence the calculation is done with double precision, whereas when using `1`, the calculation is done using single precision (because of the cast to float).

If you replace the cast to `double` in the first equation or if you change `1.0` into `1.0f` in the second equation, you'll obtain the same result.

Comment: "simple precision" ==> "single precision" ?

Comment: The whole calculation is not actually done with double precision, just the division and the addition to `add`.  `((float) count[i] + 1)` is done with only single precision. The numerical result is the same with the small values in this example, but it would differ with other data.